# RxJs piped subject not emitting value

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I have some implementation for WebSockets that i've done with RxJs support.

```
listen<T>(action: Action): Observable<T> {
    return this.subject
      .pipe(
          filter(value => value.action === action),
          map(value => {
              delete value.action;
              delete value.id;
              return value;
          })
      );
}
```

This method returns piped instance of Subject that emits all messages that comes to WebSocket instance in websocket.onmessage callback.

```
ws.onmessage = ({data}) => this.subject.next(JSON.parse(data));
```

The problem is that i have two components that uses this method to listen some type of messages and i only can listen one action at all.
For example, if i have somethig like this:

```
this.websocketService.listen('incomingStream').subscribe(m => console.log(1));
this.websocketService.listen('incomingStream').subscribe(m => console.log(2));
```

and i always get 1 in console. I want to listen this event in multiple times at the same time.

**UPD.1**

i use
"rxjs": "^6.2.1",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",

**UPD.2**

i just return property `source` and it started to work properly

```
listen<T>(action: Action): Observable<T> {
    return this.subject
      .pipe(
        filter(value => value.action === action),
        map(value => {
          delete value.action;
          delete value.id;
          return value;
        })
      )
      .source;
  }
```

i done it randomly and now i don't understand why that's started to work

Comment: it works good when i delete ```filter``` function from ```listen``` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just return property source and it started to work properly

```
listen<T>(action: Action): Observable<T> {
    return this.subject
      .pipe(
        filter(value => value.action === action),
        map(value => {
          delete value.action;
          delete value.id;
          return value;
        })
      )
      .source;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) operator

```
listen<T>(action: Action): Observable<T> {
    return this.subject
      .pipe(
          filter(value => value.action === action),
          map(value => {
              delete value.action;
              delete value.id;
              return value;
          }),
           share()
      );
}
```

Comment: try using ReplaySubject instead of normal subject

Comment: doesn't work, its interesting, because i was trying to demonstrate this problem in simple example, but there is all work perfect https://codepen.io/looffee/pen/zapxZe?editors=1111

Comment: try publishReplay(1), .refCount()

Comment: doesn't work, but when i remove ```.pipe(...)``` and just ```return this.subject;``` in ```listen``` method then all observers get a message

Comment: It’s probably the rxjs version then. Or this filter is filtering all requests